# Remove elements from a list of file in a directory

Tags: python, list

I have a little problem and I cannot understand why my program do this thing.
Can you help me?

I have a directory with a lot of different files.
I need a list of the ".TXT" files (yes, uppercase).

My code:

```
def listFile():
    files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
    for f in files:
        if (f[-4:] != ".TXT"):
            del files[files.index(f)]
```

But I don't know why the list doesn't have only the ".TXT" elements.

My directory's elements:

```
['OrdinaFile0.3.py', 'OrdinaFile0.4-p2.py', 'OrdinaFile0.4-p3.py', 'OrdinaFile0.5-p2.py', 'OrdinaFile0.6-p2.py', 'TxtToXls-p2.py', 'aula1.TXT', 'testFiles.py', 'testxlwt.py']
```

The list produced by the code:

```
['OrdinaFile0.3.py', 'OrdinaFile0.4-p2.py', 'OrdinaFile0.6-p2.py', 'aula1.TXT']
```

Have you got any idea? Thanks.

Comment: You can just use: `files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and f.endswith('.TXT')]`... You shouldn't be removing element from a list you're iterating over, and using `.index()` repeatedly is inefficient and unnecessary

Comment: Excellent point not removing elements from a list you're iterating over, will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be easily done with `glob` module:

```
import glob, os
files = [f for f in glob.glob('*.TXT') if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

Note that not all Operating systems(For eg. Windows) have case sensitive file names, so `.txt` and `.TXT` are same for such OS.

The problem with your code is that you're modifying the list while iterating over it, don't do that. Iterate over a shallow copy instead.

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques):

> To change a sequence you are iterating over while inside the loop (for
>   example to duplicate certain items), it is recommended that you first
>   make a copy. Looping over a sequence does not implicitly make a copy.
>   The slice notation makes this especially convenient:

```
for f in files[:]:
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it all with the comprehension. This way you won't have to iterate through your list and find what files have that `.TXT` extension. Plus this is more `pythonic`.

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and f.endswith('.TXT')]
```